# Memory efficient representation of ``model.matrix``

Tags: r

Assume we have a large `data.table` object with model variables:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(pryr)
library(caret)

df <- rnorm(10000000, 0, 1) %>% matrix(., ncol = 10) %>% as.data.table
df[,factor_vars:=LETTERS[sample(1:26, 1000000, replace = T)]]
df[,factor_vars2:=LETTERS[sample(1:5, 1000000, replace = T)]]
```

I'm looking for an efficient way of making a model variable matrix from the data. At the moment the best way I've found is by using `caret::dummyVars` in the following manner:

```
dd_object <- dummyVars(~ -1 + V1 + V2 + V3 + V4 + V5 + V6 + V7 + 
                         V8 + V9 + V10 + I(as.character(factor_vars)) +
                         I(as.character(factor_vars2)),
                       data = df)
```

Note that this creates a very convenient object for exporting and recreating without the original data.

```
object_size(dd_object)
R> 17.3 kB
```

On the other hand, same as with the `base::model.matrix`, it still retains the inefficiencies of the `matrix` object when dealing with many zeroes, i.e.:

```
MM1 <- predict(dd_object, newdata = df)
object_size(MM1)
R> 392 MB
object_size(df)
R> 96 MB
```

Note that the sizes can blow up very easily with more dummy variables added and etc., this is just for demonstration purposes.

**My question:** I want to use the same model-matrix object for various known modelling packages (`glm`,`glmnet`,`xgboost` and etc). The sparse matrix representation from `Matrix` packages does sound nice and efficient, but not every package is able to work with it, and `as.matrix(.)` transformation is a pain in that case.

Are there any known solutions for my case? I'm looking for something with greater efficiency than the base `matrix` (possibly like sparse matrices) and the capability of forming a storeable `model.matrix` object just like `caret::dummyVars` is able to do.

The desired workflow could be something along the lines of

`fread %>% predict(dummyVars_object, newdata =.) %>% predict(some_Model, newdata =.)`

Comment: hmm.  `dummyVars` does *not* produce a model matrix, in the standard sense; it saves only the information about the levels of the factors etc..  If `predict.dummyVars` produces a data frame with appropriate factor levels, then as far as I can see your desired workflow should Just Work with most R models that have a `predict()` method. Do you know it won't?